# fedex not working india as origin magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, api, rest-api, fedex

I tried almost all available methods to sort out but nothing happens. For the USA as origin, it works perfect in testing mode but when I change origin to India with same details as I registered to FedEx it stops working.

Please suggest how to solve this.

Comment: please refer http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/shipping/fedex.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i followed that link also . In that link its not mention how to modify FedEx for India as origin .